# How to create an instance template based on an existing template using terraform in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, harshicorp

There is a way to create templates using gcloud command.
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/create-instance-templates#based-on-existing-template

Suggest a proper way to implement this.

This can be done from using option called create similar on GCP console.I have tried this documentation but unable to find a way to implement this using terraform.
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/create-instance-templates#based-on-existing-template

This can be done from using option called create similar on GCP console.

Comment: Terraform build and deploy. It does not extract config to reuse it. Think if you start from scratch, a fresh new project: How terraform will create the template with the way you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by importing the existing template to terraform via [1], then you can either copy and paste the `google_compute_instance_template` code to reuse it with your changes.

[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance_template#import